# Nothing was saved in the database

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, database-connection

I'm new to Visual Studio 2010 and MySQL. I'm creating a form where the user will enter the information to be added in the database. No errors occur, however when I check MySQL the data that I've entered was not saved in my database. Can someone check my code for errors or lack of correctness? Please help. Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
private void button_adduser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=timekeeping;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=admin;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;

        command.CommandText = "insert into users(addfname, addmname, addlname, addposition, addcontact, addemail, addbday, addusername, addpassword) values(@fname, @mname, @lname, @position, @contactnumber, @emailadd, @birthday, @username, @password)";
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@mname", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@position", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@contactnumber", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@emailadd", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@birthday", SqlDbType.Date));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters["@fname"].Value = addfname.Text.ToLower();
        command.Parameters["@mname"].Value = addmname.Text.ToLower();
        command.Parameters["@lname"].Value = addlname.Text.ToLower();
        command.Parameters["@position"].Value = addposition.Text;
        command.Parameters["@contactnumber"].Value = addcontact.Text;
        command.Parameters["@emailadd"].Value = addemail.Text;
        command.Parameters["@birthday"].Value = addbday.Text;
        command.Parameters["@username"].Value = addusername.Text;
        command.Parameters["@password"].Value = addpassword.Text;
        connection.Open();

        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");

    }
```

Comment: As the answers state, add command.ExecuteNonQuery(); at the end, but also use the using statement for anything that implements IDisposable, e.g. a database connection. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Also note that you can use `command.ExecuteScalar()` if you are returning a single value (for instance, the ID of the newly inserted record). You should also use the `using` statement to ensure that the `Dispose` methods are called for the command and the connection. The entire code should look something like this:

```
using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using(MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "insert into users(addfname, addmname, addlname, addposition, addcontact, addemail, addbday, addusername, addpassword) values(@fname, @mname, @lname, @position, @contactnumber, @emailadd, @birthday, @username, @password)";
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@mname", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@position", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@contactnumber", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@emailadd", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@birthday", SqlDbType.Date));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        command.Parameters["@fname"].Value = addfname.Text.ToLower();
        command.Parameters["@mname"].Value = addmname.Text.ToLower();
        command.Parameters["@lname"].Value = addlname.Text.ToLower();
        command.Parameters["@position"].Value = addposition.Text;
        command.Parameters["@contactnumber"].Value = addcontact.Text;
        command.Parameters["@emailadd"].Value = addemail.Text;
        command.Parameters["@birthday"].Value = addbday.Text;
        command.Parameters["@username"].Value = addusername.Text;
        command.Parameters["@password"].Value = addpassword.Text;

        //Execute command
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got a new problem though. When I click the add there is an error message stating "Input string was not in a correct format." What might be the cause of this?

Comment: @schadi: open a new question.  Be sure to put the stack trace and the *entire* error message in it.  You might want to post the code you are using AND point out the exact line that the error is occuring on.

Answer (score 2):

You have failed to execute your command.  Try:

```
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You added the parameters, opened the connection but forgot to execute the command. Put

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

before your alert box.

As an added bonus you'll probably want to wrap things in a using statement. This will ensure your objects are disposed of properly and your connection is closed;

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
{
    using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
       command.Connection = connection;
       /// the rest of your database code goes here
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` after you open the connection.

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute command to save, you are only opening a connection.

Comment: You should give the OP some idea of what that is - if they forgot something so basic, they may not know what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing this code:

```
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```